# How to encode url parameters in golang?

Tags: go

Is there any go package to encode url?I need to encode a parameter(type in map[string]interface{}) before it was transfered in url.

Maybe the parameter likes:`map[string]interface{}{"app_id":"you_api","app_sign":"md5_base_16","timestamp":"1473655478000"}`

How to encode it and what the encoded result would be?

Comment: Please add how the generated URL should look like. Currently the question is too vague.

Comment: https://host:port/path?para={"key1": value1,"key2":"value2"}, 
I want to encode the parameter(in map structure) and transport it with json_encoded @RolandIllig

Answer (score 5):

There is the one of method to get it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{"app_id": "you_api", "app_sign": "md5_base_16", "timestamp": "1473655478000"}
    json_str, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(json_str[:]))

    values := url.Values{"para": {string(json_str[:])}}

    fmt.Println(values.Encode())

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can view how to urlencode a 'key-set' for send a request (like query params or form values)

```golang
import "net/url"
encoded := url.Values{}
encoded.Set("grant_type", "urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey")
encoded.Set("apikey", conf.Apikey)
```

For further information have a look here:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoCloudant/blob/a8ad3a7990f04ea728bb327d6faea6af3e5455ca/cloudant.go#L117

Here a few-lines-library that wrap the builtin library for execute HTTP request used in the previous code:
https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests